# XULrunner10 to detect CiscoWebCommunicator Plugin on Mac Os

Tags: macos, mozilla, cisco, xulrunner, cucm

I am newbie on XULrunner based application development on MAC OS.

We are planning to develop a SWT based application(jar) which would have the Cisco CWIC capabilities on Mac OS environment.
        We package the XULrunner version 10 SDK inside the SWT application for browser rendering.
        SWT window renders the UI components as expected.
        When trying to access the installed Cisco Web Communicator plugin v3.1.2 CWIC throws 'Plugin Not Available' error as the XUL runner could not identify\access the Ciso Web Communicator plugin which is installed on '~/Library/Internet Plugin' path.

```
    There is a 'plugin' folder and 'plugin-container.app' in the XULrunner SDK.

    We need the following clarifications from experts,

        1. Is the SDK enough to detect the Cisco Web Communicator plugin ? If so,
                1. One of the open caveats in Cwic v3.0.s is 'CWIC plugin does not load if Firebug enabled during page loading'
                            1. Is there a way to check that XULrunner enables and loads Firebug ? If so
                                    1. What are the steps to disable that ?
                2. What are the configuration or 'preferences' changes needed ?
                3. Are we need to run the plugin-container.app with the Cisco Web Communicator plugin path from the SWT application ?
                4. Is there any document for XULrunner 10 plugin process available ?


        2. If the SDK is not enough are we need to build the source to detect the Cisco Web Communicator plugin ? If so,
                1. What are all the files needs to be changed?
                2. Is there any document for this plugin detection process available ?

        3. Is is possible to package and detect the Cisco Web Communicator plugin in the 'plugin' folder of the XULrunner 10 SDK itself? If so,
                1. What are all the steps and configuration changes needed?
```